# No space on Ubuntu/VirtualBox because of [big] shared folder

Tags: ubuntu, mac, virtualbox, external-hard-drive

I have connected a huge external HDD (1TB) to the Ubuntu running in the VirtualBox (Mac) as a shared folder. Everything works good, but it looks like the system takes content of the external HDD drive when calculating the remaining disk space and starts yelling that no space is available.

Is there any way to change this behaviour?

Comment: "starts yelling" – How exactly?

Comment: Something like "no place left" - either by trying to write new file or as a notification on desktop.

Answer (score 0):

If the host computer (I assume that is the Mac) has no need to access the contents of the external drive, you could use USB passthrough and then pass the hard drive to the Ubuntu virtual guest.

You would have to have the guest additions installed in the Ubuntu guest, but I think you already took care of that. On the bottom right of the console window of the Ubuntu guest you will see a bunch of icons representing hard drive, sound, and so on. One of them looks like a USB connector. Click on it and then go look for your hard drive.

Comment: I know, I tried with USB passthrough and it tells device is assigned to VM but ubuntu does not show it as device. Last idea as an explanation was that by HDD is USB 3.0 one and you need specific drivers on Ubuntu for that